# How to modify the content of previous commits?

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm modifying the content of a past commit called "commit2", with the following steps:

```
    #1 checkout the commit we want to modify
    git checkout ad4fe51
    
    #2 amend the commit with new changes
    git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit
    
    #3 remove files from folder
    git rm -rf .
    
    #4 return
    git checkout -

    #5 rebase
    git rebase --onto @{-1} ad4fe51
```

However, at step 5 it pushes back the things i have modified in the commit (#2).

If I call push origin, commit2 contains all modifications correctly, however,

"commit7" will contain `{ commit7.txt, newfile1.txt, newfile2.txt }`

How can I avoid this?

I recorded a gif with the steps: https://i.imgur.com/qc9fVeA.gif

Obs: I'm avoiding using --interative to skip the editor as I'm automating this process.

Comment: You cannot modify a commit.  Ever.  Commits are immutable.  Although it is quite common to create a new commit with the same (or very similar) tree, commit message, etc., you should understand that you CAN NOT modify a commit.

Answer (score 0):

I think your life will be much easier if you *start* with `git rebase`:

1. Identify the commit you want to modify.
2. Run:

   ```
   git rebase -i COMMIT^
   ```

   E.g., if you want to edit commit `ad4fe51`, run:

   ```
   git rebase -i ad4fe51^
   ```
3. In the pick list, change `pick` to `edit` for that commit and save the list.
4. Make the changes you want and `git add` the files.
5. Run `git rebase --continue`.
6. Update your commit message, if necessary, and save it.

You're all done!

---

If I put the following script in `$HOME/bin/git-edit` (or somewhere else in my `$PATH`)...

```
#!/bin/sh

CID=$(git rev-parse "$1")
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '1 s/pick/edit/'" \
    git rebase -i "${CID}^"
```

...then I can run `git edit COMMIT` and immediately start making changes (this takes care of both steps 2 and 3 in the above list).

Comment: I did that way to avoid the editor because im automating the process

Comment: You'll note that the solution I show at the bottom of this answer avoids the editor (because we replace it with `sed`).